# Insert or Update error due to Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `Heading` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(2000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `carousel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(225) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `imageby` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `checked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `reset_link_token` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `exp_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `blog`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `userid` (`userid`);

ALTER TABLE `carousel`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `userid` (`userid`);

ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE;


ALTER TABLE `blog`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blog_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blog_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blog_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `carousel`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carousel_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);
```

My question now is that when i am updating or inserting the boolean value in the table 'carousel' and 'column', it is showing the error written below

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`bloggin`.`carousel`, CONSTRAINT `carousel_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
> (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))

Comment: Appears that you're inserting a row with a userid which doesn't exist in the user table.

Comment: Why on earth does blog have three identical foreign key constraints?